# Access outside root div from a click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to access the div `.extra-suppliers.mobile.only` when I click `.mobile-select-supplier a`. Here's the full code:

```
<div>
    <div class="four wide column dashed">
       <div class="ticket-buy-block">
          <div class="price-block">
             <span class="ticket-main-price">2615Kč</span>
             <span class="ticket-main-total">Total: Kč2669</span>
             <div class="mobile-select-supplier">
                <a class="ui button ticket-buy-button primary-color">
                   <div class="mobile only book-chevron">
                      Select
                   </div>
                </a>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flight-proposals">
             <a href="#" class="ticket-proposals" target="_blank">
                <span class="proposal-name">Kiwi.com</span>
                <span class="proposal-amount">
                   Kč1427
                </span>
             </a>
             <div class="suppliers">
                <div class="trip-options"><a><i class="small circular info icon"></i><span class="label">See Details</span></a></div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="extra-suppliers mobile only" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

I have the following markup multiple times and each click needs to find the `.extra-suppliers` that it is within the div related to the clicked `a` element. I tried this:

```
$( '.mobile-select-supplier a' ).click(function( event ) {
  $( this ).parents().find('.extra-suppliers.mobile.only').css('display','block');
});
```

It works, but triggers `css()` on all of the `.extra-suppliers`. I need an alternative way without `parents()` to find the root div and the closest `.extra-suppliers` div to the button.

Answer (score 1):

To go with `parent`, you have to go over `closest`, for the getting the right parent:

```
$('.mobile-select-supplier a').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.four.wide.column.dashed').parent().find('.extra-suppliers.mobile.only').show();
});
```

Best way would be to give the parent a selectabe class, like `.parent`:

```
$('.mobile-select-supplier a').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.parent').find('.extra-suppliers.mobile.only').show();
});
```

Comment: because directly will select all of extra-suppliers. i need the one that is within the div. within the $( this )

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because `parents()` gets all parent elements, so you're effectively looping through every parent element and repeatedly setting all the contained `.extra-suppliers` elements to be visible.

Instead, use `closest()` to find a single fixed parent then `next()`. Try this:

```
$('.mobile-select-supplier a').click(function(event) {
    $(this).closest('.four.wide.column.dashed').next('.extra-suppliers.mobile.only').show();
});
```

Note that it would be better to put a single class on the parent element instead of using the four styling classes to retrieve the parent `div`, I simply did it here to create a working example.

Comment: `.four.wide.column.dashed` is not the parent of `.extra-suppliers.mobile.only`. Did the same error before. ;) The unnamed `div` is the parent.

Comment: @IlanHasanov no problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

better first select blocks and save to variables then make actions or add selector to `parents('selector')`, watch example below, method parents select all parents if you didn't add selector

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var row = $('div.four.wide.column'),
      button = row.find('.mobile-select-supplier>a'),
      block = row.next('.extra-suppliers.mobile.only');
  
  $(button).click(function(){
    //block.toggle();
    $(this).parents('div.four.wide.column').next('.extra-suppliers.mobile.only').toggle();
  });
      
});
```

```css
.four.wide.column.dashed{
  background-color:#fff;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 2em;
}
.extra-suppliers.mobile.only{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class="four wide column dashed">
       <div class="ticket-buy-block">
          <div class="price-block">
             <span class="ticket-main-price">2615Kč</span>
             <span class="ticket-main-total">Total: Kč2669</span>
             <div class="mobile-select-supplier">
                <a class="ui button ticket-buy-button primary-color">
                   <div class="mobile only book-chevron">
                      Select
                   </div>
                </a>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flight-proposals">
             <a href="#" class="ticket-proposals" target="_blank">
                <span class="proposal-name">Kiwi.com</span>
                <span class="proposal-amount">
                   Kč1427
                </span>
             </a>
             <div class="suppliers">
                <div class="trip-options"><a><i class="small circular info icon"></i><span class="label">See Details</span></a></div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="extra-suppliers mobile only" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```